# Snippet with configurable text

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I want to make a code snippet where a part of the snippet text is substituted with a value that can be configured by the user.

Following [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) I tried using an environment variable like

```
"${env:MYVALUE}"
```

and a configuration variable like

```
"${config:my.value}"
```

Both the environment variable and the user defined settings exist but they are not substituted. Are these variables not supported in snippets and if not is there some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables from documentation mentioned in the question are only used in configuration files. Snippets have their own set of supported variables. Taken from [the source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/editor/contrib/snippet/snippetVariables.ts) these are:

```
CURRENT_YEAR
CURRENT_YEAR_SHORT
CURRENT_MONTH
CURRENT_DATE
CURRENT_HOUR
CURRENT_MINUTE
CURRENT_SECOND
CURRENT_DAY_NAME
CURRENT_DAY_NAME_SHORT
CURRENT_MONTH_NAME
CURRENT_MONTH_NAME_SHORT
SELECTION
CLIPBOARD
TM_SELECTED_TEXT
TM_CURRENT_LINE
TM_CURRENT_WORD
TM_LINE_INDEX
TM_LINE_NUMBER
TM_FILENAME
TM_FILENAME_BASE
TM_DIRECTORY
TM_FILEPATH
BLOCK_COMMENT_START
BLOCK_COMMENT_END
LINE_COMMENT
WORKSPACE_NAME
```

Details can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables).